# Problems getting Experience Manager to publish without Session Preview

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, configuration, session-preview

I am starting an incremental implementation of Experience Manager (XPM). Due to architectural constraints, we will first implement XPM without Session Preview before rolling out web application changes to enable Session Preview partially (for component presentations) and then fully (for page alterations) in later phases.

The problem I am having is that XPM is not publishing content when I click Finish Editing, and worse still, is not publishing newly created pages (resulting in a 404 whenever a new page is created in XPM). I have recreated this behaviour on a dev system which has Session Preview installed, by disabling session preview AND removing the Session Preview webservice endpoint from the Staging publication target Session Preview settings.

I dont see why if Session Preview is disabled, a valid oData webservice endpoint is required on the publication target Session Preview settings, am I missing the point, or perhaps some other configuration setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a defect in 2013 GA where it would still attempt to use Session Preview in some cases. That has been fixed in the upcoming service pack.

For now, I guess you'll need to work around it by having at least one working OData web service. You might be able to get away with not configuring a session database and such, I don't know.

Comment: I tried using a normal oData service endpoint and it gives an error: Unable to update the changes using the oData service. The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Comment: In that case you have to set it all up, or wait for the service pack (or possibly request a hotfix if it's urgent)

Answer (score 3):

The way XPM figures out the destination for publishing is by mapping the URL you are on to the URL settings for the Publication Target (not the ones for Session Preview but the ones specifically for republishing purposes). Please check that those are configured and it is possible to map one of the Targets to your URL.

It is (very briefly) described on a bottom of this section:

[Setting up publishing for Experience Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_3F88811BFF4D468AB436867A43082D94)

Comment: I have added my staging site, however I get the error message: Publication Target does not contain valid OData Service configuration